# the union of a chain of well ordered sets is well ordered

Tags: set-theory

I have difficulty to understand the following claim in "Naive set theory" of Halmos on page 68. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a continuation chain of well-ordered sets, and $U$ be the union of these sets. If $A\subset U$ such that $A\neq\emptyset$, then there exists $C\in\mathcal{C}$ such that $A\cap C\neq\emptyset$. Then, $A\cap C$ has a minimal element $\bar{x}$ since $C$ is well ordered. Then, the first claim is that $\bar{x}$ is the minimal element of $A$, and I have managed to prove this. The proof follows from the continuation relation. The second claim in the book is that $\bar{x}$ is the minimal element of $U$. I couldn't see why this is correct. If it is correct, then $\bar{x}$ must be the minimal element of $C$. However, $A$ is an arbitrary nonempty subset of $U$; it can consist of only one element and why that element must be the minimal element of $U$? Do I miss a point or do I misunderstand the related statement in the book?

Thanks for your help...

Comment: What is a "continuation chain"?  What do you mean by the "continuation relation"?  Does that mean that the ordering relationship remains consistent among elements of the chain?

Comment: @RobertShore "Continuation chain" should mean that, if $A\subseteq B$ are two elements of the chain, then $A$ is an initial segment of $B$. (Without that requirement, the union of the chain can fail to be well-ordered.)

Comment: mind stating why $\overline{x}$ is the minimal element of A? I was actually about to ask a question about that myself but if you have the answer then I'd love to hear it!

Comment: @jsmith If $A\subset C$, then $A=A\cap C$, and hence $\bar{x}$ is the minimal element of $A$. If $A\not\subset C$, then there exists $y\in A$ such that $y\not\in A\cap C$. Then, there exists $D\in \mathcal{C}$ such that $y\in D$. Since $C\neq D$, either $C$ is a continuation of $D$ or vice versa. If $C$ is a continuation of $D$, then $D\subset C$ and hence $y\in C$, which is a contradiction. If $D$ is a continuation of $C$, then $C$ is an intial segment of $D$. This implies that $\bar{x}<y$ since $y\not\in C,y\in D,\bar{x}\in C$. Therefore, $\bar{x}$ is the minimal element of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A,B\in\mathcal C$ then $(A\subset B\lor B\subset A).$ If $A\subset B$ then also $$\forall a\in A\,(\,\{y\in B:y< a\}\subset A\,).$$

If $\emptyset\ne S\subset \bigcup\mathcal C,$ consider some (any)  $A\in \mathcal C$ such that $A\cap S\ne \emptyset.$ Let $a=\min (S\cap A).$

Suppose by contradiction that $a>b\in S.$ Then $b\in B$ for some $B\in\mathcal C.$

Now $b\not \in A$ because $a\in S$ and $b<\min (S\cap A)\,;$

but $(A\subset B\lor B\subset A),$ so $A\subset B,$ so $b\in \{y\in B:y<a\}\subset A,$ so $b\in A$ a contradiction.

Therefore $a=\min S.$

Comment: In a "continuation chain" if $A\subset B$ then any member of $B$ \ $A$ is greater than any member of $A$.